# Find a[j]=j in O(log n) time

Tags: algorithm

How can I find if a sorted array has an element a[j]=j in O(log n) time?(no duplicates)

Comment: You have to visit n nodes ...

Comment: is it allowed to contain duplicate values?

Comment: @belisarius You're forgetting that the array is sorted.  This is actually a very interesting problem.  I think there's some way to apply binary search.

Comment: @Jon Rodriguez may be I am missing something. But to be sure the full array has a[j]=j, you should check all nodes

Comment: Is this "for all j", "for any j", or "for a specific j"? Those are 3 different questions, neither of which is implicit in the given text.

Comment: @belisarius - if it's sorted, and you check a[n/2] and see that its value is lower than the value you're looking for, you can dismiss everything between 0 and n/2.

Comment: @Jon Rodriguez, no in the worst case you must compare every index. Anyway, I think the questioner needs to clarify this for us.

Comment: Ok, I mis-understood that he wanted to check if that is valid FOR ALL j

Comment: It's not a well-formulated question, gotta say that.

Comment: @user470379 Please go on and edit the question

Comment: It would be better if asker edited the question - I wouldn't want to make assumptions on what is being asked.

Comment: I think the question is "Given sorted array a, is it possible to determine whether or not there exists j such that a[j] = j in O(log n) time?"  To which I answer yes.

Comment: @andand It seems so. Very different from the posted question, though.

Comment: Interesting enough, this very bad formulated question is getting up-votes!

Answer (score 13):

If the array is of integers and cannot contain duplicates, you can just use binary search.

E.g. let's say we have the array:

```
a[0] == -30
a[1] == 1
a[2] == 200
a[3] == 200
a[4] == 204
a[5] == 205
a[6] == 206
a[7] == 207
```

- First try a[floor(avg(0,7))] (i.e.
  a[3]).  This equals 200.  200 is too
  big.
- So move to the lower half.  Try
  a[floor(avg(0,2))] (i.e. a[1]).  This
  equals 1.  Hurray!

Your binary search will either successfully find some j for which a[j] == j, or it will fail by running out of places to look.  Since a binary search is O(log n), you will know within that time complexity the value of j or that no such j exists.

Note that if multiple values of j satisfy the condition, you will just find an arbitrary one of them.

Comment: @Manish, please update your question. We are not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I thought of Binary search too by seeing log n .But imagine a scenario like this a[0]=0 a[1]=1 a[2]=2 a[3]=3 a[4]=4 a[5]=5 a[6]=6 a[7]=7 .Now if I started from a[4] I cant say that only 1 direction will have solution .Here both of them do ....I mean that I cannot always cut the input by half. But yeah if only one such instance is asked then I can say I  have log n algo.

Comment: @Manish, I am assuming that the OP means "does there exist any j for which a[j] == j"

Comment: @Manish: In that case when you find a[4] = 4 you're done.  You have determined that there is in fact a j such that a[j] = j, and in that particular case you've done it in O(1) time which is also O(log n) time.

Comment: @Manish Note that user434507 's answer is correct in pointing out that binary search might not work if the array is allowed to contain duplicates or floats.

Comment: @Jon, agreed, I was going to say that this algorithm only works for an array of integers.

Comment: -1 doesn't work -- consider what happens if every element in your array is 7 initially.

Comment: @Chris Dodd:  You are correct.  See my comment 2 comments before yours.  But I will add that qualification to the answer itself to be clear.

Answer (score 8):

If it can contain duplicate values, or it is a floating point array, you can't. Counterexample: a[2k]=2k+1, a[2k+1]=2k+1 or 2k+2. Worst case scenario, you have to check a[2k+1] for all k.

If it is an integer array and all values are distinct, then you do binary search. Look at a[1]-1 and a[n]-n. If they are the same sign, the answer is no. If they have different signs, look at a[n/2]-n/2. It's either zero (and then you have your answer), or one of the intervals (1,n/2) or (n/2,n) will have different signs at the ends. Take that interval and repeat.

Comment: Could you please provide two separate counterexamples for the cases where a can contain duplicates and where a can contain floats?

Comment: The counterexample for floats is a[2k]=2k+0.5, a[2k+1]=2k+1 or 2k+2. The point is that the binary search will only work if we're looking for a single solution or a contiguous array of solutions. If the array can contain floats or duplicates, there may be as many as n/2 disjoint solutions, and we may have to check them all by hand.

Comment: Ah, I understand now.  Upvote.  However, it might be a lot easier for visual learners like me to understand if you would provide full examples depicting an entire array rather than just two elems.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming duplicates are disallowed:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
find_elt_idx_match( int *a, int lo, int hi )
{
  int elt, idx;
  while ( lo <= hi )
    {
      idx = lo + ( hi - lo ) / 2; /* Thanks, @andand */
      elt = a[ idx ];
      if ( elt == idx )
        {
          return 1;
        }
      if ( elt < idx )
        {
          lo = idx + 1;
        }
      else
        {
          hi = idx - 1;
        }
    }
  return 0;
}

int
main( void )
{
  int a[ 100 ];
  /* fill a */
  /* ... */
  printf( "idx:elt match? %c\n", find_elt_idx_match( a, 0, 99 ) ? 'y' : 'n' );
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There you go +1, except what's up with the 1970s-style function notation?

Comment: Not to nit-pick, but idx = ( lo + hi ) / 2; can overrun the range of ints.  Better to use idx = lo + (hi - lo) / 2; (ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Computer_usage)

Comment: @David: Not sure what you mean. `printf()` vs. `cout`? I intended only C, not C++.

Comment: @William I think he means the indentation of braces and blocks (2 spaces for a brace, then two more for the block)

Comment: Ew, non-recursive solution. :-(

Comment: @William: no no, I was talking about `[type]\newline[function name]` :P but I exaggerated the time frame

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getFirstMatchedIndex(int[] oArry)
        {            
            int i = 0;
            while(i < oArry.Length )
            {
                if (oArry[i] == i)
                    return i;
                else if (oArry [i] > i)
                    i=oArry [i];
                else
                    i++;

            }
            return -1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If duplicates are not allowed, and your list is sorted according to obvious order a[i] < a[i+1] (strictly less, not equal!), then it is also true that a[i]-i < a[i+1] - i, so it follows that a[i]-i <= a[i] - (i+1).  (Note the inequality becomes "<=".) In other words, the values of a[i]-i, throughout your list, are in order.  Search for the value 0=a[i]-i, using binary search on a sorted list.